# Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated()

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to implement Google2FA with this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/2fa-in-laravel-with-google-authenticator-get-secure/

I use Laravel 5.8 and in the tutorial they're using something like 5 I guess, thats why I dont have the 
`app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php`

anymore. I have LoginController.php and RegisterController.php

If I try to login and test, I get this error:

Argument 2 passed to 
`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\User given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 109`

Code:

```php
private function authenticated(Request $request, Authenticatable $user)
    {
        if ($user->google2fa_secret) {
            Auth::logout();

            $request->session()->put('2fa:user:id', $user->id);

            return redirect('2fa/validate');
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
    }
```

User model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use ChristianKuri\LaravelFavorite\Traits\Favoriteability;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Favoriteability;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'slug', 'premium_ends', 'is_banned', 'ban_reason', 'ban_ends', 'apikey', 'admin',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'google2fa_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
?>
```

LoginController

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
        ]);
    }

    private function authenticated(Request $request, Authenticatable $user)
    {
        if ($user->google2fa_secret) {
            Auth::logout();

            $request->session()->put('2fa:user:id', $user->id);

            return redirect('2fa/validate');
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
    }

    public function getValidateToken()
    {
        if (session('2fa:user:id')) {
            return view('2fa/validate');
        }

        return redirect('login');
    }

    public function postValidateToken(ValidateSecretRequest $request)
    {
        //get user id and create cache key
        $userId = $request->session()->pull('2fa:user:id');
        $key    = $userId . ':' . $request->totp;

        //use cache to store token to blacklist
        Cache::add($key, true, 4);

        //login and redirect user
        Auth::loginUsingId($userId);

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your `User` model

Comment: add your `LoginController` code

Comment: updated again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the typehint you have on that method signature for `authenticated`:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
```

You don't need it. If you feel you do need it, you need to make sure you alias that interface correctly so it doesn't think you are referring to `Authenticatable` in the current namespace. You could use the contract `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

...

protected function authenticated(Request $request, Authenticatable $user)
```